# How can I allow API access to a GKE K8S cluster without modifying the HTTP client

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-apiserver

I set up a k8s cluster on GKE.

I want to control it via the k8s REST API (so, looking at deployments on pods and whatnot, but not accessing what is actually running on the k8s cluster over SSL). I have gotten the appropriate bearer token (`curl --insecure [request]` works) and can make API requests. However, the SSL certificate isn't valid for my client (it's java, if that matters). I can't easily modify the client to accept the new root cert at this time.

I have been digging around and have examine the following three options:

- incorporate the cluster's root CA cert into another cert chain (from my limited understanding of TLS, I'm not sure this is possible) that exists in my client already.
- replace the cluster root CA cert (so that I can use something my client has in its keystore). [This](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/kubeadm-certs/#external-ca-mode) implies you can do this with vanilla k8s, but [this](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-trust) implies that you cannot using GKE: "An internal Google service manages root keys for this CA, which are non-exportable."
- allow k8s API access without TLS. I haven't seen anything about this in [the docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/controlling-access/#api-server-ports-and-ips), which are pretty explicit that k8s API access over the network must use TLS

Are any of these viable options? Or is my best choice to modify the client?

Comment: can you import the k8s REST API's root ca into the trust store of your java client?  I am not fully following the options you presenting.  Usually the options are either importing the root ca certificate into REST client trust store, get your certificate signed by a trusted CA that java trusts by default (Let's Encryt, etc .. ) Of course disable ssl verification in the client which never is a good thing'

Comment: Ah, thanks. I'm trying to avoid modifying the client in any way, @Yan. But maybe I can't avoid it.

Comment: Can you get a certificate signed by a trusted CA like let's encrypt(free) or other paid sites?

Comment: I haven't use google cloud but can you get GC to provisioned an SSL cert that java would trust by default

Comment: I am guessing at this point you are using a self signed certificate that you created on the k8s server side?

Comment: The k8s server on gke has a root cert that is used to set up TLS when it serves up the API. I haven't found a way to replace that root cert.

Comment: Who is the Root CA of the certificate presented by the k8s rest api?

Comment: Google is, I believe, but a private internal CA. This seems to say that: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-trust

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on some other feedback (in a slack), I ended up putting a proxy between my GKE cluster and my client. Then I can just add the GKE cluster k8s ca cert to the proxy's keystore (and don't have to modify the client). For my purposes, I didn't need to have the proxy use SSL, but for production I would.

Comment: that works.  For production you can get a certificate signed by Trusted authority which java trusts by default and the client will be able to connect without issues

Answer (score 0):

There is an article named **"Access Clusters Using the Kubernetes API"** (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-api/) that addresses your concerns about how to query the REST API using a **Java Client** (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-api/#java-client)

If you are using the Java app inside a POD, you can import your cluster's CA to your Java Trust Store (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19509-01/820-3503/6nf1il6er/index.html). The CA certificate of for your cluster is inside all pods running within your cluster on `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt` directory. More information in (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-api/#without-using-a-proxy)

Regarding your questions:

**1.-** Import the your cluster's CA cert to your trust store.

**2.-** You can't set your own CA in GKE, but you can rotate the CA certificate if needed (https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/credential-rotation)

**3.-** You can't deactivate TLS communication in GKE (https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-trust)

Your best option is to use the official Java Client or ADD the CA to your current development.

Comment: Thanks, so it sounds like your suggestion is to modify the client. Thanks for the links!